# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 1, size is 1

Tags: android

While i am trying to get value from arraylist,i got the following errors.My sample code is below.test is the name of my array list

String s = test.get(1);

```
04-05 11:51:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(901): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 1, size is 1
04-05 11:51:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
```

)
    04-05 11:51:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2170)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invalid location 1, size is 1` means that the ArrayList starts with index[0]. If you use `get(1)` you will receive the second entry.

Answer (score 2):

Your string array is size of 1, that means it only has one string and at 0.  What are you trying to get from the string array?  I think the code you want is

```
if(test.size() >=1)
   String s = test.get(0);//magical numbers are evil by the way the good book told me so
```

Please not that this is very bad practice, and you should really post more of your code so we know why you need the first or second string of that array.

Comment: What if the next time its size is zero..?

Comment: that is why magic numbers are evil, I have no idea what his assumptions are for this code, maybe he always appends some character or something. Thanks sandy I'll append the answer to safegaurd for that

Answer (score 2):

Just check for `test.size()` in your case its 1 that's why use `String s = test.get(0);`

Always first check the `size of your list` or `array's length`. And then get the values according to it. **Remember all array and list always start with 0 in this case you last element is always your list's size() - 1.**

Answer (score 0):

your ArrayList size is 1 so its position will be 0

try this code

```
String s= test.get(0);
```

Comment: What if the next time its size is zero..?

Comment: then it will return null you should check if(s != null) and proceed further in your code or you can also use Iterator to check ArrayList is empty or not for eg: Iterator<String> iter= test.iterator(); if(iter.hasNext()){String s= iterator.next();}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your arraylist size is one you can get by using test.size();

so now as we all know array indexing starts with zero you can fetch test.get(0); to retrive first element in arraylist and if you try to fetch next element that is test.get(1) you will get IndexOutBound Exception...